Alomost sure convergence
I was studying the various types of convergence and I met a question for almost sure convergence. Consider random varibales $X_n,X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, $\Omega$ is a probability ($\mathbb{P}$) space. By the definition of almost sure convergence, We say $X_{n}(\omega)\to X(\omega),n\to\infty$ almost surely if $$\mathbb{P}(\{\omega:\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega)=X(\omega)\})=1.$$ If we donote the set $A=\{\omega:\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega)=X(\omega)\}$, does it mean that for any $\omega\in A$, for any $\epsilon>0$, one can find $T$ (does not depend on the choice of $\omega\in A$) such that $|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|<\epsilon,n>T$? Thanks!

Surely, $T$ will depend on $\omega$.

$A={\omega:\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega)=X(\omega)}=1$???????

Take $\Omega=(0,1)$ and define $X_n(\omega) = \frac{1}{n\omega}$ for $\omega\in\Omega, n \in{1, 2, 3, ...}$. Then $X_n\rightarrow 0$ surely but the property you seek fails.

You have not defined what $t$ is, and if you mean $n$ that would be uniform convergence. Convergence simply says that for every $w\in A$ there exists an $N$ such that for $n>N$, $|X_n(w)-X(w)|<\epsilon$. $N$ is allowed to depend on $w$.

Sorry, it is a typo. I have fixed it.

The answer is still the same, but switch $N$ to $T$ if you like.
